# Bootstrap Button Group with Float

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to create a group some buttons and float them to the right of a div container:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="caption">
    <p>Here is some blurb...</p>
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from this fiddle the buttons break-out of the div when I apply float-right:

https://jsfiddle.net/xa9wvouc/6/

I could set the caption to have a min0height but that feels like a hack? What is the correct way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap, wrap the button-group in a row (see code below). From here you can adjust the margin-right on button-group as you see fit.

https://jsfiddle.net/meppiel/ysx7nvk4/1/

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button-group pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you that worked. Is it valid to add the row class to the surrounding caption div class so as to minimise mark-up?

Comment: Sure thing. And yes, you can remove the row div and just add that class to the caption div. Updated the plunk to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you apply pull-right to a button-group, it means that the button-group will be float and the height of its parent div will be collapse. So to avoid collapsing parent div, you need to apply clearfix class to the parent div

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="caption clearfix">
    <p>Here is some blurb...</p>
      <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```